# No ruby interpreter configured for the project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to configure Ruby interpreter in RubyMine ? I have not understood what the website of Rubymine is trying to say. please help me
thanks!i have a project name "Untitled" and its class name is naqash.rb , but when i try to run ! it says an error , no SDK specified. so how i can solve that problem

Comment: Go to Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Ruby SDKs and Gems  What is there?

Comment: There is no list actually of any SDK or GEM.  how to install them ?

Comment: i cant add picture due to my less reputation

Comment: its saying - nothing to show

Comment: i am using windows 7.

Comment: how to set interpreter path ? is interpreter in rubymine folder or what should i do ?

Comment: check my answer, just download, install, restart, then check rubymine

Answer (score -1):

Well since you are on windows 7 you need to install ruby so follow this http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Then go back to preferences and see if your sdks is there.

Comment: brother - there is no preferences option. where is the preferences button - i am using RubyMine 7.1.2

Comment: might be settings on windows, I'm using osx. it should be found in the toolbar at the top, just click file, or help and should be in the dropdown selections